# Java how to end a do-while loop using boolean input from user?

Tags: java, loops, boolean, do-while

So I want to have a user input either "true" or "false" to exit the loop. As I have it now, it exits the loop no matter what I type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Color guard flags
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Flag yourFlag;
    double weight;
    boolean correct;
    do {
        System.out.println("Hello!\nWhat colors are your silk? (most common two)\nHow long is your pole (in feet)?"
                + "\nWhat have you named your flag?\nHow heavy is your flag (in pounds)?");
        yourFlag = new Flag(kb.next(), kb.next(), kb.nextInt(), kb.next(), kb.nextDouble());
        if (yourFlag.getWeight() >= 7) {
            System.out.println("That sounds like a cool flag! It sounds pretty heavy though.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("That sounds like a cool flag!");
        }
        System.out.println("You've entered that your flag " + yourFlag.getName() + " is " + yourFlag.getWeight() + " pounds and "
                + yourFlag.lengthOfPole + " feet long. It also has the pretty colors " + yourFlag.silkColor1 + " and " + yourFlag.silkColor2);
        System.out.println("Is that correct? (True or flase)");
        correct = kb.nextBoolean();
    }
    while (correct = false);
```

Btw, yes this is a program about color guard

Comment: Alternative: `while(correct == false)`

Answer (score 2):

`correct = false` is an assignment.

You should use `!correct` to test if `correct` is `false`.

sample code;

```
do {
    //
}
while(!correct);
//while(correct == false)
```

and if you want it otherway

```
do {
    //
}
while(correct);
//while(correct == true)
```